# O365 PowerShell Pull SubLicense

Tags: powershell, office365

I am trying to pull a list of all users in my O365 Tenant and if they are licensed, the list of sublicenses they have been granted.  The following code works great to list out my sublicenses:

```
$userlicensetest = get-msoluser -userprincipalname "steve.dorr@merrillcorp.com"
$userlicensetest.licenses[0].servicestatus
```

ServicePlan :: ProvisioningStatus

----------- :: ------------------

INTUNE_O365 ::    PendingActivation

YAMMER_ENTERPRISE  :: PendingInput

OFFICESUBSCRIPTION  ::  Success

So I tried to modify code I found online to include the sublicense information.  Here is what I have built so far:

```
$ReportPath = "c:\users\userlist.csv"
Add-Content -value ("UserPrincipalName"+","+"IsLicensed"+","+ "Licenses”"+","+ "SubLicenses") -Path $ReportPath
$AllUsers = Get-MsolUser -All 
foreach ($User in $AllUsers)
{
 $UserPrincipalName = $User.UserPrincipalName
 $IsLicensed = $User.IsLicensed
 $Licenses = $User.Licenses.AccountSkuId
 $SubLicenses = $User.Licenses[0].servicestatus

 Add-Content -value ($UserPrincipalName+","+$IsLicensed+","+$Licenses+","+$SubLicenses) -Path $ReportPath
}
```

The problem is it is only pulling the header line from the sublicense query and not all the lines of detail.  So the line for myself in the CSV looks like:

Steve.Dorr@MerrillCorp.com  TRUE    mymerrillcorp:ENTERPRISEPACK    Microsoft.Online.Administration.ServiceStatus Microsoft.Online.Administration.ServiceStatus Microsoft.Online.Administration.ServiceStatus Microsoft.Online.Administration.ServiceStatus Microsoft.Online.Administration.ServiceStatus Microsoft.Online.Administration.ServiceStatus Microsoft.Online.Administration.ServiceStatus Microsoft.Online.Administration.ServiceStatus

Which does not give me the detail lines I needed.

How do I pull all the lines that Licenses[0].servicestatus generates into the CSV file?  I don't care whether it flattens it out and goes across more columns, or takes up multiple lines in Excel.

Thanks.

So since I posted this question I have worked a little on it.  I do not have a perfect solution that puts this into a nice neat CSV file, but I do have a routine which now drops all this information into a text file.  Below is my code.

```
$MyCredentials = Get-Credential -Message "Enter Office 365 Email & Password"
Connect-MsolService -Credential $MyCredentials
$ReportFile = "C:\temp\O365Data.txt"
" " | Out-File $ReportFile  #erases the file if it exists

$AllUsers = Get-MsolUser -All 
foreach ($User in $AllUsers)
{
 $UserPrincipalName = $User.UserPrincipalName
 $IsLicensed = $User.IsLicensed
 $Licenses = $User.Licenses.AccountSkuId
 $SubLicenses = $User.Licenses[0].servicestatus
 $OneLine = $UserPrincipalName + " " + $IsLicensed
 $OneLine| Out-File $ReportFile -Append
 if($User.Licenses[0].servicestatus) {$User.Licenses[0].servicestatus | Out-File $ReportFile -Append}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create the report you'll need to create custom objects to hold the properties you are interested in.

The following will take into account all the different licenses that could be applied to a user and then generate a csv with one user listed per line.

```
# Connect to o365
$MyCredentials = Get-Credential -Message "Enter Office 365 Email & Password"
Connect-MsolService -Credential $MyCredentials

# Prepare result file
$ExportFile = ".\o365Output.csv"
Remove-Item $ExportFile
$Result = @()

# Query all Msol Users
$AllUsers = Get-MsolUser -All

foreach ($User in $AllUsers)
{
    # Generate a new object for each user
    $ReturnObject = [pscustomobject]@{
        UserPrincipalName = $User.UserPrincipalName
        IsLicensed = $User.IsLicensed 
        Licenses = [string]$User.Licenses.AccountSkuId
    }

    # In the event multiple licenses are found append properties for each license
    foreach ($License in $User.Licenses)
    {
        if($($License.ServiceStatus.ServicePlan.ServiceName).count -eq 1)
        {
            $ReturnObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $License.ServiceStatus.ServicePlan.ServiceName -Value $License.ServiceStatus.ProvisioningStatus
        }
        else
        {
            for($i = 0; $i -lt $($License.ServiceStatus.ServicePlan.ServiceName).count; $i++)
            {
                $ReturnObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $License.ServiceStatus.ServicePlan.ServiceName[$i] -Value $License.ServiceStatus.ProvisioningStatus[$i]
            }
        }
    }   
    $Result += $ReturnObject 
}

# Combine properties from all returned objects
$Properties = $Result | ForEach-Object { Get-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name } | Select-Object -Unique | Sort-Object
$Headers = @("UserPrincipalName")
$Headers += $Properties -notlike "UserPrincipalName"

# Export to csv
$Result | Select-Object $Headers | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $ExportFile

# Open csv
Invoke-Item $ExportFile
```